# Docker: Why is /etc/resolv.conf unreadable? Breaks DNS

Tags: dns, docker

I'm using Docker 1.6 on a CentOS 7 host, using CentOS 7 containers.
In most of my containers, DNS doesn't work, because /etc/resolv.conf cannot be read, even by root:

```
[root@7ba55011e7ab etc]#  ls -l /etc/resolv.conf 
ls: cannot access /etc/resolv.conf: Permission denied
```

This happens in most of my containers, even containers that are created directly from the standard Docker centos:latest image.  (This problem also occurred when I was using the standard Docker debian image.) The only container in which resolv.conf is readable is the very first one I created from the stock centos image.

Needless to say, I've bounced Docker multiple times, as well as rebooted the host machine.  I've also tried using --dns *hostname* in the OPTIONS in /etc/sysconfig/docker.  But of course that doesn't help because it's not the contents of resolv.conf that are a problem, but rather the fact that I can't read it (even as root).

I understand that /etc/resolv.conf is "bind mounted" from the host's /etc/resolv.conf.  The host's copy of this file looks fine, and the permissions look reasonable:

```
[root@co7mars2 etc]# ls -l /etc/resolv.conf 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 106 Apr 30 18:08 /etc/resolv.conf
```

I am not able to umount /etc/resolv.conf from within the container:

```
umount -f -r /etc/resolv.conf 
umount: /etc/resolv.conf: must be superuser to umount
```

Is there a fix for this?

I see some related issues on the Docker github site, such as https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2267, but they address enhancements for complex use cases, rather than my situation, where I'm just dead in the water.

By the way, I've tried this on two separate and unrelated CentOS 7 hosts, with the same results.

Thanks.

Comment: Is SELinux enabled on the docker host? If so, try to set it to permissive mode for a test using `setenforce 0` and see if that helps.

Comment: That's it!  SELinux was set to Enforcing.  Setting it to Permissive resolved the problem.  You're a genius.

Comment: In my opinion `/etc/resolv.conf` in docker is not bind-mounted as you can modify it. I truncated it and it is now empty despite the host one being in its original state.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Daniel t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358259/daniel-t)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979656/docker-why-is-etc-resolv-conf-unreadable-breaks-dns#comment48079600_29979656), [issue 11396](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/11396) mentions that you can give the container write access (meaning at least read access too) in any one of the following ways:

> - Disable SELinux for the entire host: `setenforce 0`

See [issue 7952](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7952):

```
# Example of proper behavior on fresh btrfs system when SELinux is in Permissive mode
[~]$ getenforce
Enforcing
[~]$ sudo setenforce 0
[~]$ getenforce
Permissive
[~]$ sudo docker run fedora echo "hello world"
hello world
[~]$ sudo setenforce 1
[~]$ sudo docker run fedora echo "hello world"
echo: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

> - Set the directory SELinux policy to allow any container access:

```
    chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /var/db
```

> - Make the container `--privileged`.
>     This disables not only SELinux constraints but also the default cgroups restrictions:

```
    docker run --privileged -v /var/db:/data1 -i -t fedora
```

> - Disable SELinux policy constraints for this container only:

```
    docker run --security-opt label:disable -v /var/db:/data1 -i -t fedora
```

> - Run the container processes as SELinux process type `unconfined_t`:

```
    docker run --security-opt label:type:unconfined_t -v /var/db:/data1 -i -t fedora
```